# CSharpScripting security

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, .net-standard

I want to disable use of `System.IO` in user scripts, so that user could not write scripts such as

```
new System.IO.StreamWriter("a.txt");
```

or

```
using System.IO;
new StreamWriter("a.txt");
```

I can do it just analyzing code with Roslyn, but I think it will affect performance. Is there any other approaches?

Comment: I think performance is the least of your problems. It will be hard to correctly list and detect all possible variants of accessing the file system.

Comment: You can't completely avoid it. Take reflection for example `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.IO.StreamWriter"), args: new object[] { "a.txt" })`. Type name can be located in variable that's initialized at runtime. There's no way you could avoid all possible scenarios

Comment: Is there any approach to remove access to reflection?

Comment: @medegor44 . I don't think it's possible without own version of .net runtime